# PhpStorm stuck on connection to PHP Remote Interpreter from docker on Windows 10

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm

I'm on Windows 10 with Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4 with all disks shared and PhpStorm 2017.2.4 (also tried with latest version).

Docker daemon has activated the: `Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS` option.

I'm using docker-compose and all docker containers are working fine. The issue appears when I try to setup remote PHP Interpreter in PhpStorm.

[image]

After I press OK in "Configure PHP Interpreter" the PhpStorm is stuck at Checking PHP Installation and I cannot move forward.

I looked in the docker daemon logs and I observer an error, I'm not sure that this is the error that makes PhpStorm stuck or not.

Do you have any suggestion on how can I make PhpStorm to work with remote php interpreter from docker?

> [14:50:39.831][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] proxy >> GET /v1.24/_ping
>   [14:50:39.832][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] Dial Hyper-V socket 60e9b7fb-c9cd-4a07-a5dc-dd752b277321:23a432c2-537a-4291-bcb5-d62504644739
>   [14:50:39.842][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] Successfully dialed Hyper-V socket 60e9b7fb-c9cd-4a07-a5dc-dd752b277321:23a432c2-537a-4291-bcb5-d62504644739
>   [14:50:39.845][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] proxy << GET /v1.24/_ping
>   [14:50:39.897][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] proxy >> GET /v1.24/containers/json?all=true
>   [14:50:39.897][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] Dial Hyper-V socket 60e9b7fb-c9cd-4a07-a5dc-dd752b277321:23a432c2-537a-4291-bcb5-d62504644739
>   [14:50:39.900][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] Successfully dialed Hyper-V socket 60e9b7fb-c9cd-4a07-a5dc-dd752b277321:23a432c2-537a-4291-bcb5-d62504644739
>   [14:50:39.931][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] proxy << GET /v1.24/containers/json?all=true
>   [14:50:40.178][DnsUpdater     ][Info   ] Network configuration change detected
>   [14:50:40.178][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script '$(Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress 8.8.8.8).InterfaceIndex[0]'...
>   [14:50:40.378][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] proxy >> POST /v1.24/containers/create [rewriteBinds]
>   **[14:50:40.383][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] Rewrote mount /d/projects/feedy:/opt/project:rw (volumeDriver=) to /d/projects/feedy:/opt/project:rw
>   [14:50:40.570][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] Failed to read proxies/http from snaphshot p9p.MessageRerror{Ename:"No such file or directory"}**
>   [14:50:40.570][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] proxy >> POST /v1.24/containers/create
>   [14:50:40.570][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] Dial Hyper-V socket 60e9b7fb-c9cd-4a07-a5dc-dd752b277321:23a432c2-537a-4291-bcb5-d62504644739
>   [14:50:40.581][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] Successfully dialed Hyper-V socket 60e9b7fb-c9cd-4a07-a5dc-dd752b277321:23a432c2-537a-4291-bcb5-d62504644739
>   [14:50:40.844][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] proxy << POST /v1.24/containers/create
>   [14:50:41.064][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] proxy >> POST /v1.24/containers/9280500170ec7fd7b858b90e58d1afa253735b0bdd4e08f8db6bf683801536af/attach?stdin=true&stdout=true&stderr=true&stream=true
>   [14:50:41.064][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] Dial Hyper-V socket 60e9b7fb-c9cd-4a07-a5dc-dd752b277321:23a432c2-537a-4291-bcb5-d62504644739
>   [14:50:41.065][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] Successfully dialed Hyper-V socket 60e9b7fb-c9cd-4a07-a5dc-dd752b277321:23a432c2-537a-4291-bcb5-d62504644739
>   [14:50:41.066][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] Upgrading to raw stream
>   [14:50:45.262][DnsUpdater     ][Info   ] Network configuration change detected
>   [14:50:45.262][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script '$(Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress 8.8.8.8).InterfaceIndex[0]'...
>   [14:50:50.371][DnsUpdater     ][Info   ] Network configuration change detected
>   [14:50:50.371][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script '$(Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress 8.8.8.8).InterfaceIndex[0]'...

Comment: Try removing share from the D drive, apply changes, then share the drive again. It seems that the share is broken somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but is not workin. I can say that I have all my services already dockerized using docker-compose and they are working fine with mapping.

Comment: Don't you forget to check the option?: https://i.imgur.com/Y7H1qJX.jpg

Comment: @AlexSlipknot no, already checked

Comment: I've never use docker-compose with PhpStorm. I have the next settings: https://i.imgur.com/ZNPqYR9.jpg Also maybe this can help you: https://ollyxar.com/blog/docker-phpstorm-windows

Comment: Have you managed to fix this issue? I'm using Docker Desktop on Windows 10. After remote PHP interpreter setting selected and applied I get a message "Checking PHP Installation" and PHPStorm stops responding completely. The only way I can shutdown PHPStorm is using windows task manager.